# node.js package written in rust to perform db queries - how to make it efficiently?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm a rust newbie, want to write a node.js package related to database querying.

I'm using napi-rs for the package.

In node.js we have own async stuff, in rust we have similar thing called "tokio" for async stuff.

I want to create ORM for node.js, and learn rust at the same time, so idea is to construct queries on node.js side and perform them on rust side, give response back to node.

I see two ways:

1. Use tokio with tokio-postgres
2. Not to use tokio, instead to write own database adapter library which will rely on node async functionality and node sockets. Not even sure if I can do this but can try. Not sure if that makes sense.

First way is way more simple, but will it work? Is efficient to include tokio to node.js package?

Comment: Writing this in Rust with the intention of calling it from Node doesn't seem like a good fit to me since there's not a ton to gain by doing in Rust vs writing it in JS, so definitely be aware of that. If the goal is purely as a learning experience go for it though.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm happy to inform that I could actually do a benchmark and get a better results with rust napi plugin then with node library! Just a bit better, 10% better, but it is only beginning

Answer (score 0):

`execute_tokio_future` method of napi works just perfect! Details on how to use it I found here: https://forum.safedev.org/t/adventures-in-rust-node-js-and-safe/2959/10

I was able to get benchmark with better results using rust addon than a node library, so the idea paid off.